# std::find/std::find_if for custom container c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, find

I'm trying to find an object with some attribute value in a custom container that contains an array of objects of another class.

```
MyIterator<WindowWithTitleButton> WindowList::FindTitle(string title_find)
{   
    auto iter = std::find(this->begin(), this->end(), title_find);
    return iter;
}
```

"Title" is an attribute of class `WindowWithTitleButton` and I'm trying to find object in the container with that "title", but I can't figure out how.

I tried to do that with std::find_if

```
bool WindowList::ContainsTitle(string cmpr, string title)
{
    int result = cmpr.compare(title);
    if (result == 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
MyIterator<WindowWithTitleButton> WindowList::FindTitle(string title_find)
{   
    MyIterator<WindowWithTitleButton> iter;
    auto i = std::find_if(iter = begin(), iter = end(), ContainsTitle((*iter).GetTitle(),title_find));
    return i;
```

But it gives me an error C2064 - term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments.
How can I properly use this function without error?

Comment: Have you looked at `std::find_if`?

Comment: And what is the problem with the code you have? Please provide [mcve], including error messages (if any).

Comment: @jkb yes, and I can't figure it out either. I'll update the question with my attempt to use find_if

Comment: The body of that `ContainsTitle` function would typically be written `return cmpr == title;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this:

```
auto i = std::find_if(iter = begin(), iter = end(), 
                      ContainsTitle((*iter).GetTitle(),title_find));
```

You've made a few mistakes:

- The iterators should be sent in by value:
  `std::find_if(begin(),end(), ...`
- The [*UnaryPredicate*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Predicate) functor should have the signature `bool(const YourWindowsClass&)` - that is, it should take *one* argument and return `true` or `false`.  The algorithm will loop through all windows in your container and the *UnaryPredicate* functor will be called with a reference to each element at a time in the container - not an iterator.
- The *UnaryPredicate* also needs something to compare with and you can solve that by capturing it in a lambda for example. That's what `[&title_find]` does in my example below.

```cpp
MyIterator<WindowWithTitleButton> WindowList::FindTitle(std::string title_find) {
    return std::find_if(begin(), end(),
                        [&title_find](auto&& window) {
                            return title_find == window.GetTitle();
                         });
}
```

`window.GetTitle()` is here a member function that returns something that can be compared with a `std::string`.

If the elements in your container are of type `WindowWithTitleButton` you can replace `auto&& window` with `const WindowWithTitleButton& window` to make it clearer.

Comment: It helped! I was just trying to figure out the ```auto&& window``` and it works fine, but when I input ```const WindowWithTitleButton& window``` instead, I get an error with ```window.GetTitle()```, because WindowWithTitleButton is a derived class from class Window (error: the object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with the member function      object type is: const Window)

Comment: @alex_shevch I think you've forgotten to make all member functions that doesn't change the element `const` qualified, that's why. Remove `const` and make it `WindowWithTitleButton& window` and it should compile - but I strongly suggest that you go through your member functions to make those `const` that should be :-)

Comment: Right, it really was a problem and I missed it. Thank you very much for helping the beginner!)